# python threading computation load

Tags: python, multithreading

I need a process monitoring a directory, and if there is a new file, process the file. So I implemented this basically as below.

My question is simple: While monitoring, I need to keep doing `if` check with an infinite loop (`while True`). How much is the computation load for that? Is it severe? Or is there a better way to do so (e.g., event-driven way when a new file is monitored)?

For information, please assume that a huge process is running on the other side which generates files to monitor, and the `do_analyze` takes around 15 min.)

```
# a thread monitoring the result directory every 10 min.
# if there is a new file, push in the queue.
from treading import Timer
file_checker = Checker(some_directory)
timer = Timer(10*60, file_checker.check())
timer.start()

while True:
    filename = file_checker.pop()
    if filename:
          do_analyze(filename)
```

Comment: You need to add operating system at mimimum (and probably python version). Most operating systems allow adding some sort of watch for file changes in directory, for example creation. For example for windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx . To answer your question - yes, its expensive, it will take 100% of single processor.

Comment: you can use filesystem inotify, for example you can implement it using this library: http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html

Comment: Thanks! Then how about the computation of `sleep()` function? If I check intermittently, like `if filename: do_analyze(filename); else: sleep(10)`, would it be better?